# LibreNMS and HAProxy - force https

Tags: php, laravel, haproxy

I configured LibreNMS with a private IP address running only over http (no SSL). Now I want to connect the domain to it via HAProxy and force SSL. It works correctly, i.e. redirection and encryption from the domain to the server with a private IP address, but unfortunately when I look inside the source code of the website, I see references to http instead of https. The result is a lack of images and js and css files not loading.

**HAProxy config is simple:**

```
frontend www-https
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mycert.pem
        use_backend LibreNMS if { req.hdr(host) -i librenms.mydomain.com }

backend LibreNMS
    server serv1 192.168.10.17:80
```

I set LibreNMS `config.php` variable `$config['base_url']` to `https://librenms.mydomain.com` but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is on Laravel's side. I added `\URL::forceScheme('https');` in php files. It works, but it interferes with LibreNMS source files. I still don't know how to fix it in LibreNMS directly.

Comment: `\URL::forceScheme('https');` in `AppServiceProvider` method `Boot`